# How to compute normals for a segment line in 3D

Tags: math, opengl, normalization, opengl-3, normals

I have exported some hair particules from Blender (a hairstyle). These are composed of several lines (GL_LINES). My openGL program displays these particules without any problem. Now I just want to apply light properties on these particules. Blender does not export the normals vectors so I need to compute them by myself. I know the following rule :

If we define a line segment as [AB] in two dimensions, 
we have dx = xB - xA and dy = yB - yA, then the normals are N1(-dy, dx) and N2(dy, -dx).

I hope I did not make any mistake.

But I don't know the rule for a 3D space line segment definition if I add the z dimention in my line segment coordinates (for instance A(5, 2, 3) and B(0, 0, -5)).

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: There's no single normal for a line in 3D. Instead the line itself is a normal for a plane.

Comment: What Aki Suihkonen said. Or, worded the other way around: There is an infinite number of normals that lie on a plane perpendicular to the line. To calculate a single normal, you need something "planar" like a triangle. A line, on the other hand, can rotate around itself in every possible way without you being able to see a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Since Aki forgot that comments aren't answers:

Lines in 3D space don't have a normal. Technically, lines in *2D* space don't have a normal either; they have *two* normals.

There are an infinite number of directions that are perpendicular to a line in 3D space. All of these normals are in the same plane, but with different directions. Without some more advanced algorithm (likely based on adjacent lines), there is no way to pick one of these normals over another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But a line in openGL, as you know, is not a real line. It has a tiny surface. The proof is glLineWith() method. I you zoom to a line with a width of 10 pixels you will see that the line is a tiny polygon. So a line with a width of 1 (default value) is also a tiny polygon. So the solution would be to conserve the points coordinates of each line (A(x, y, z) and B(x, y, z)) and create (just for normals computing) a polygon merged with the line. Hence, I could compute normals for this line ?

Comment: @user1364743: OpenGL lines don't have a surface. And glLineWidth just sets the width of the line on the screen. OpenGL lines are not tiny cylinders or polygons, which you could "blow up". I think you suffer from a few very strong misconceptions of OpenGL. OpenGL doesn't know what a scene is. It doesn't even know what geometry is. All it sees are points, lines and triangles that are drawn as 2D flat shapes onto a 2D flat framebuffer. All resemblance of 3D just happens by clever application of math that creates a image that looks like 3D, but actually isn't.

Comment: @user1364743: Regarding the line width: OpenGL uses a line rasterizer very much like a Bresenham line rasterizer. Google for "think Bresenham lines", that's what OpenGL does.

Comment: Ok but you think luminosity computing can be realized from this kind of algorythm ? Sorry to insist but I realized a 3d graphic engine that manage all types of mesh included particular system. I managed luminosity computing with GLSL shaders for all types of mesh excepting for particulars system. Currently for a specific project I need to compute hairstyle. I have the mesh but no light implementation yet. I know that it already exists some technologies about that but I want to have a complete understanding of how it works.

Comment: For example when your create a sphere with hair particules on it, if you move the object you'll see that hair particules change of color because of spot light. So I think there is a normals computing on them or an other algorythm which can simulate the same effect. Do you have some informations about that ? Thanks in advance. It's very hard to find this kind of informations.

Comment: Another solution could be to replace the line segments by very tiny quads. For instance a quad with width of 1 pixel and a height of what you want. This solution could resolve the problem of luminosity, I think. What do you think about that ?

Comment: @user1364743: Stack Overflow is not a discussion site. It's not a place where you start brainstorming solutions in comments. Your question is about generating a normal for a line segment. If you want to ask about how best to represent line segments and such, that's a new question and should be asked as such. It's not clear at this point what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that you can get two vectors to begin with, and it looks like that's what you are saying, call them v, w, to get a normal vector take the cross product.  It's not a bad idea to normalize v, w to begin with, depending on the situation.  The cross product can be given by:

```
v x w =(v_2w_3 - v_3w_2, v_3x_1 - v_1w_3, v_1w_2 - v_3w_1),
```

Here v_i is the ith component of v and so on. The numbers next to each other represent multiplication.  You, of course, have plus or minus this vector giving two possibilities.

Comment: btw, to get the two vectors that you start with, just use any two non-parallel segments in the polygon that you have described.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. I will try this. I have another proposition. Tell me if it would be possible. Suppose I have a line segment [AB]. I compute two polygons at the two extremities (just for normals computing) perpendicular to the lines. Hence, I can compute five normals by polygon separate by 72 degrees (for instance). So to compute luminosity on the line segment I would have 10 normals merged with the polygon. This would increase the luminosity effect in 3D, I think. Do you think it's possible ?

Comment: I don't know about your luminescence effects, but you'll only get different (non parallel) normals if the polygons you have are non-parallel in the 3-D space that you're in. I would suggest drawing a picture.

Comment: I edited the formula of your answer since there were two typos.
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, and even used the indefinite article "a". Some have suggested there is no norm to a 3D line segment by saying there is an infinite number of them. Yet, miss the indefinite article "a" --- which I assume could mean any 1 of infinite.

What happens when someone does not have two vectors to start with?

vector is the unit vector of the line segment or vector.
create a rotation matrix around vector to obtain 1 of infinite norms

It took some time, but using Eigen template library and 10000 random test samples. Here is the code:

```
#include <Eigen/Core> 
#include <Eigen/Geometry> 
Eigen::MatrixXd samples = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(10000, 3); // 3x3 Matrix filled with random numbers between (-1,1)

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
{
    Eigen::Vector3d vector(samples(i, 0), samples(i, 1), samples(i, 2));
    vector.normalize();
    Eigen::Vector3d zaxis(0, 0, 1);
    Eigen::Vector3d xaxis = zaxis.cross(vector);
    xaxis.normalize();
    Eigen::Vector3d yaxis = vector.cross(xaxis);
    yaxis.normalize();

    Eigen::Matrix3d m;
    m(0, 0) = xaxis(0);
    m(0, 1) = yaxis(0);
    m(0, 2) = vector(0);

    m(1, 0) = xaxis(1);
    m(1, 1) = yaxis(1);
    m(1, 2) = vector(1);

    m(2, 0) = xaxis(2);
    m(2, 1) = yaxis(2);
    m(2, 2) = vector(2);

    // one of two easy points to use to get 1 of infinite norms --- the other being (1, 0, 0)
    Eigen::Vector3d point(0, 1, 0);
    point = m * point;
    point.normalize();

    auto norm = point.cross(vector);
    norm.normalize(); // 1 of an infinite number of norms

    auto check = norm.dot(vector); // verify with dot product
    if (std::abs(check) >= 1e-12)
    {
        //complain
    }
}
```